# Windows for freedesktop.org .desktop files

Tags: shortcuts

Is there a tool to open [freedesktop.org .desktop files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Entries) on Windows?

I need that to open internet shortcuts created on KDE:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=text-html
Type=Link
URL[$e]=http://www.mobygames.com/game-group/switchblade-series
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-off or are you trying to script it?

You could just open the `.desktop` file in any text editor and look for the line that starts with `Exec=` then run that.

Granted, that's not going to "just work" on Windows, different executables, paths, etc. Perhaps you should post one of the .desktop files in question.